# How to display list of user with account status in spring

Tags: java, jquery, spring, extjs, jsp-tags

I want  to display list of user with account status as a locked or unlocked. also admin able to search user from list of users. how to implement this functionality using spring, java ? or any jquery component provide this functionality?

Comment: Bit more information needed... How are you storing your users? If you are using LDAP, spring-ldap is fairly easy to use to connect and query LDAP directories.

Comment: where do you get this list? what objects are in the list (users) and what properties does users have if thats the case.

Comment: @pap: i m storing user information in database not in ldap. so i have written some domain, service  class for user details. i want to populate user details from database and display at jsp page. on this page i want to unlocked user. also admin able to search user using user name. so how can i implement search functionality ?

Comment: @RMT:i m storing user information in database. i have user object. user name , user id, login items attribute is present in database. i want to populate user details from database and display at jsp page. on this page i want to unlocked user. also admin able to search user using user name. so how can i implement search functionality ?

Comment: @pap: in our application authentication is done through ldap and then retrive user role from database. so i want to display  user details from database. after populating user details i want to unlocked user.

Comment: @Pap: also i want to add search functionality on user list. so after display list of users admin able to search user by user name. how can i display list of user with search functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what i can tell, inside your JSPs you should use JSTL

you can use that to iterate through all the users in your list. Also you can add extra logic, like if the user is active highlight it green (or something like that). 
example:

`<table>
<c:foreach var="user" item="${users}">
<tr><td>${user.firstName}</td></tr>
</c:foreach>`

This is a quick example (sorry not formatted) that will take all the users in the list and display the first name in a table. Its really quite simple to use. The only thing you need to know is at the begining you need to is : and I use the prefix C because it is the standard for "Core".
<%@ taglib uri = "http://java.sun.com/jstl/core" prefix = "c"%> Hoep this helps,

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. Do you have any example so that i can understand it in better way...

Comment: also i want to add search functionality on user list. so after display list of users admin able to search user by user name. how can i display list of user with search functionality?